# Windows: Automate sequence of command line for several different applications

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, command-line, command

What's the best way to run several Windows cmd commands with just 1 click? Probably batch file? For example:

1. Run `php artisan down` on production project root
2. Push (commit) development repository to master (Git)
3. Rebase (pull) production repository from master (Git)
4. Run these commands at root project folder step by step

   - `composer update`
   - `s3 put blabla/blabla/assets/ public\assets\ /acl:public-read /sync /sub:withdelete`
5. Run `php artisan up` on production project root

These steps should wait for previous step to complete before proceeding. Any other tools suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to use a batch file for this?

Comment: Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a .bat file for that. If you want to run this regularly (e.g. for a kind of nightly build/refresh) it also might be useful to create a recurring task using the windows scheduler and to put the comands in there instead of using a batch file. If you decide to do so you can still trigger the task manually at any time by using the command line `schtasks /run /tn <yourtaskname>`.